# 400 error from React calling node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks

i try to call some register from react front to my node.js back using axios  but i got a 400 error saying:

http://localhost:9000/user/register 400 (Bad Request)

Here my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TutorialDataService from "../../services/TutorialService";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


    const Register = () => {

      const user = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
      }

      const [userData, setUserData] = useState(user);
      const [error, setError] = useState('');
      const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);

      const handleChange = e => {
        setUserData({ ...userData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
      }

      const saveUser = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const  data = {
          name: user.name,
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password
        };
        TutorialDataService.signUp(data)
          .then(response => {
            setUserData({
              name: response.data.name,
              email: response.data.email,
              password: response.data.password
            })
            setSubmitted(true);
            console.log(userData)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            setError(error);
            console.log(error);
          })
      }

      const newUser = () => {
        setUserData(user);
        setSubmitted(false);
      }

      const { name, email, password, confirmPassword } = userData;

      const btn = name === '' || email === '' || password === '' || password !== confirmPassword
      ? <button disabled>Inscription</button> : <button>Inscription</button>

      // gestion erreurs
      const errorMsg = error !== '' && <span>{error.message}</span>

      return (

        <div className="signUpLoginBox">
          <div className="slContainer">
            <div className="">
              <div className="formContent">
                <form onSubmit={saveUser}>

                  {errorMsg}

                  <h2>Inscription</h2>
                  <div className="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" id="name" onChange={handleChange} value={name} autoComplete="off"  />
                    <label htmlFor="pseudo">Name</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="inputBox">
                    <input type="email" id="email" onChange={handleChange} value={email} autoComplete="off" required />
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                  </div>

                  <div className="inputBox">
                    <input type="password" id="password" onChange={handleChange} value={password} autoComplete="off" required />
                    <label htmlFor="password">Mot de passe</label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="inputBox">
                    <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" onChange={handleChange} value={confirmPassword} autoComplete="off" required />
                    <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirmez le mot de passe</label>
                  </div>

                  {btn}

                </form>
                <div className="linkContainer">
                  <Link className="simpleLink" to="/login">Déjà inscrit? Connectez-vous </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Register
```

my auth file node.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User');
const { registerValidation, loginValidation } = require('./validation');


router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  //LETS VALIDATE THE DATA BEFORE WE A USER
  const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  //Checking if the user is already in the database
  const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
  if(emailExist) return res.status(400).send('Email already exists');

  //Hash passwords
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  //Create a new user
  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword
  });
  try{
    const savedUser = await user.save();
    res.send( {user: user._id});
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});



module.exports = router;
```

and then in my app.js (node) is like:

```
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

app.use('/user', authRoute);
```

Validation.js (node)

```
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

    //Register Validation
    const registerValidation = (data) => {
      const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string()
          .min(6)
          .required(),
        email: Joi.string()
          .min(6)
          .required()
          .email(),
        password: Joi.string()
          .min(6)
          .required()
      });
      return schema.validate(data);
    };
```

http-common.js:

```
import axios from "axios"

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:9000",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

service.js :

```
import http from "../http-common";

const signUp = data => {
  return http.post('/user/register', data);
};
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: add-in `registerValidation`

Comment: Hi, i updated my post with all the files

Answer (score 0):

In the front end you are fetching from "/user/register" but the post in your auth file in node it's just "/register". Try making them match.

Comment: I already try  that not working and i define my route in the app js: like this  user/register. When I use the postman to try me node. Js code I use this url: http://localhost:9000/user/register and it's work so the problem is not here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put `router.get` instead of `router.post`